# php mysqli_query results nothing

Tags: php, mysql, include

I am trying to fetch data from a table using mysqli_query.
When i use the following commands it works ok:

```
$hostname = "********";
$username = "*******";
$password = "********";
$databaseName = "**************";
$dbConnected = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password, $databaseName);
```

When i try to include file with the above codes include('../htconfig/dbConfig.php');  then i do NOT get any results:

..."0 results"

```
<?php

include('../htconfig/dbConfig.php');
$dbConnected = mysqli_connect($db['hostname'], $db['username'], $db['password'], $db['databaseName']); 

if(!$dbConnected) {
    die('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '
            . mysqli_connect_error());
}
echo 'Success... ' . mysqli_get_host_info($dbConnected) . "\n". "<br>";
mysqli_set_charset($dbConnected, "utf8");

$tPerson_SQLselect = "SELECT  ";
$tPerson_SQLselect .= "ID, Salutation, FirstName, LastName, CompanyID ";    
$tPerson_SQLselect .= "FROM ";
$tPerson_SQLselect .= "tPerson ";           

$result = mysqli_query($dbConnected, $tPerson_SQLselect);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
// output data of each row
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo "Salutation: ".$row["Salutation"]. "-FirstName: ".$row["FirstName"]." ".$row["LastName"]."  -CompanyID: ".$row["CompanyID"]. "<br>";
}
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}

mysqli_close($dbConnected);
?>
```

I can not find my error..
Please help !

dbConfig.php file:

```
<?php
$db = array(
'hostname' => '*****',
'username' => '*****',
'password' => '*****',
'database' => '*****',
); 
?>
```

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: Try `require` instead of `include` - are you certain that your file is being included correctly?

Comment: i dont see anything in my browser

Comment: yes it is included correctly because  i tried echo the variables from dbConfig.php file

Comment: You're not error checking the query, you're assuming it will work as written.

Comment: please tell me how can i error check my query?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your $dbConnected should be like this if you're still using the same variable names:

```
include('../htconfig/dbConfig.php');
$dbConnected = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password, $databaseName);
```

If you want it to be $db['field'] then your ../htconfig/dbConfig.php should be like this:

```
$db = array('hostname' => 'xxxx',
            'username' => 'xxxx',
            'password' => 'xxxx',
            'databaseName' => 'xxxx');
```

**EDIT:**
Your array in dbConfig.php says 'database' but you used 'databaseName' in your $dbConnected mysqli_connect function?

Comment: i posted my dbConfig.php file at the end of the post

Comment: @N.K. check my update.

Comment: i did the check and.... Query failed

Comment: Wy dublicate question?? My question WAS NOT how to display PHP errors !!!

Comment: @N.K. Could you try the same query check if statement with != instead of !==?

Comment: @N.K. Your array in dbConfig.php says 'database' but you used 'databaseName' in your $dbConnected mysqli_connect function?

Comment: You saved my day !! Thank you very much!